# How to calculate difference in minutes between START and END times in a file using Powershell or cmd

Tags: powershell, date, difference

The file has the following content.

```
START Sun 04/17/2022 13:01:44.13 
END   Sun 04/17/2022 14:41:50.60
```

I'm trying to find a way to automate how many minutes it took from `END` to `START` time, I don't care about the seconds, just need to know how many minutes took to run.
In this example it took 100 minutes but I had to calculate manually.
I'd appreciate any feed back.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your input file is named `file.txt`:

```
$dates = [datetime[]] ((Get-Content file.txt) -replace '^\w+ +')
[int] ($dates[1] - $dates[0]).TotalMinutes  # -> 100
```

- Your date-time strings are in a format that can be cast to `[datetime]` directly.

  - To extract the date-time string from each line, the first whitespace-separated token must be removed, which the regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator can do:

    - `-replace '^\w+ +'` matches one or more (`+`) word characters (`\w`, letters, digits or `_`) at the start (`^`) of the string, followed by one more spaces, matching something like `END`   . Since no replacement string is specified, the matched string is effectively *removed*.
  - `-replace` can operate on an array as its LHS, in which case the operation is performed on each element; therefore, all lines of the input file can serve as the input at once, as returned by [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content).
- Subtracting two `[datetime]` instances yields a `[timespan]` instance representing the span of time between the two points of time:

  - Its `.TotalMinutes` property reports the span in fractional minutes (as a `[double]` instance)
  - Casting that value to `[int]` yields an integral number of minutes, using half-to-even midpoint-rounding.

Answer (score -1):

`New-TimeSpan` and the `ParseExact()` or `TryParse()` method of from an object instance of `DateTime` will help you here.

```
$Start = [datetime]::ParseExact('04/17/2022 13:01:44.13', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff', $null)
$End = [datetime]::ParseExact('04/17/2022 14:41:50.60', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff', $null)
New-TimeSpan -Start $Start -End $End
```

This will provide an output like the below:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 1
Minutes           : 40
Seconds           : 6
Milliseconds      : 470
Ticks             : 60064700000
TotalDays         : 0.0695193287037037
TotalHours        : 1.66846388888889
TotalMinutes      : 100.107833333333
TotalSeconds      : 6006.47
TotalMilliseconds : 6006470
```

Access specifically minutes by doing something similar to the below:

```
> $result = New-TimeSpan -Start $Start -End $End
> $result.TotalMinutes
100.107833333333

# Round up to 2 decimal places
> [Math]::Round($result.TotalMinutes, 2)
100.11

# Round up to 0 decimal places
> [Math]::Round($result.TotalMinutes, 0)
100
```